# Как задать стили , после того как убрал мышку (обратная функция :hover)

Tags: html, css

Когда ты наводишься на какой то блок/текст и он меняет, к примеру фон.

```
:hover {background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
```

Но это когда мы наводимся. А нужно, когда ты убираешь мышку, это плавно на место возвращалось. К примеру, у меня есть `<hr>`
У него есть ширина `width: 100px;` , когда я на него наведусь, значение `width` будет `200px` , так вот, мне нужно чтобы когда я убирал мышку, это значение менялось так же плавно как и `transition` у `<hr>`
**Вот чисто кусок кода для ясности :**

```
#nav-header hr{
    width: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
    transition: width 0.5s;
}
#nav-header:hover hr{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Когда я навожусь, блок медленно растёт в ширину, а когда убираю, он мгновенно убирается (прячется).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде все плавно работает , ширина иметься ввиду
[КЛИК](https://jsfiddle.net/9x8snwyp/)

```
#nav-header {
  width:100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: #000;
}
#nav-header hr{
    width: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
    transition: width 0.5s;
    height: 10px;
}
#nav-header:hover hr{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: странно очень. Но  у меня он не заводится. В вашем кода - да. Плавно. Но у меня она не медлеенно возвращается на место , а очень быстро.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lqdb5do/ (Вот так у меня не работает)
Почему, понять не могу..

Comment: У вас там "color" не "transition" , и как "ховер" спадает , цвет "hr" сразу становиться прозрачным , поэтому кажется что ширина не плавно идет, сделайте "transition:all .4s;"

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: Бесплатный совет, не трогай <hr>, того эффект, которого хочешь добиться, судя по ссылке, используй обычный <div>...